# Using "std::set", take elements

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In my code I used an array, I decided to try std :: set. I did this with an array:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  {
    drawNMS(true, myMassive[myStr+i]);
  }
```

myStr is added by buttons.
For std :: set, as I understand it, I need to use an iterator.
I try to do so:

```
std::set <int>::iterator iter;
for(iter=mySet.begin(); iter!=mySet.end();iter++)
{
  drawNMS(true, myStr+*iter);
}
```

Where to insert for (int i = 0; i <100; i ++) correctly so that the end result is like when working with an array?

Comment: What is `myMassive`? Could you please show a [mre] to clarfiy what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry. myMassive - int array. Filled by clicking on the buttons

Comment: This is usefull information, you can always [edit] your question. However, it's not clear to me what you are really trying to achieve here. `i` is simply a counter. Do you want to replace `myMassive`? Please show more code, so we can understand what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over first 100 elements of a set, then do this:

```
std::set <int>::iterator iter;
int counter = 0;
for(iter=mySet.begin(); iter!=mySet.end() && counter < 100;++iter, ++counter)
{
  drawNMS(true, myStr+*iter);
}
```

Comment: If C++17 is available, you may want to use struct binding to remove creating counter as local variable for loop. So your code will look like that ```for(auto [counter, iter] = {0, mySet.begin()}; iter !=...```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++20, there is std::ranges which provides [std::ranges::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ranges/advance) that works with a boundary, so your end-iterator can be found like this (not tested):

```
auto endSet100 = std::ranges::advance(mySet.begin(), 100, mySet.end());
```

This end-iterator can then be used like the original end-iterator. If you use std::advance, you have to do the boundary check yourself and the advance works on the iterator itself without returning a new iterator.

For simpler looping:

```
for (const auto& elem: std::ranges::subrange(mySet.begin(), std::ranges::advance(mySet.begin(), 100, mySet.end()))
{
    drawNMS(true, myStr+elem);
}
```

It may be a bit longer, but it states: loop a subrange from the beginning to the 100th element or all if less elements are present.